# In Espresso, specify that you want to work with the current visible AdapterView

Tags: android, android-espresso

In an activity I have a `ViewPager` with 2 tabs: "ALL" and "Filtered".
Both pages use the same `Fragment` to display the data, with the difference that the "Filtered" page filters the data by some criteria.

I want to click on an item from the "ALL" page (which might exist as well in the "Filtered" page), and if I do:

```
onData(transactionWithId(960L)).perform(click());
```

in response I get:

> AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'is assignable from class: class
>   android.widget.AdapterView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy

I then tried to refine my description by specifying an additional constraint, that I am looking for an item that is visible:

```
onData(allOf(transactionWithId(960L), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

and I got the same error.

then I thought to specify somehow, that I am looking for my item in the "ALL" tab (not sure though if this is correct):

```
onData(allOf(
      transactionWithId(960L), 
      withParent(withText("ALL")))
   ).perform(click());
```

but again the same error.

Then I tried to specify that I am looking for an `AdapterView` that is currently in front of me:

```
onData(allOf(
       is(instanceOf(Transaction.class)), 
       transactionWithId(960L))
   ).inAdapterView(allOf(
            isAssignableFrom(AdapterView.class),
            isDisplayed())
          ).perform(click());
```

and I got:

> PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view '(is
>   assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView and is
>   displayed on the screen to the user)'.

Note that I can click on an item that is displayed in an `Activity` with a single `ListView`, the challenge I am facing is when I have a `ViewPager` with multiple tabs that use one `Fragment` to display the data.
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach **should work**, I created a minimal working example [here](https://github.com/gilvegliach/StackOverflowAnswers/tree/master/EspressoViewPager).

The gist of the problem is to distinguish the two adapter views. An alternative approach would be to mark them explicitly with [tags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)). Then we can restrict the `DataInteration` with `inAdapterView()` with a custom `Matcher` on a specific tag. The complete code is still [here](https://github.com/gilvegliach/StackOverflowAnswers/tree/master/EspressoViewPager), I quote the key points:

In the adapter view:

```
boolean isFiltered = ...
AdapterView av = ...
av.setTag(isFiltered);
```

In the test:

```
@Test
public void testClickOnSecondItemInAllTab() {
    onData(instanceOf(String.class)).inAdapterView(withTag(false)) //
                                    .atPosition(1)                 //
                                    .perform(click());
}
```

And the custom view matcher on the tag:

```
static Matcher<View> withTag(final Object tag) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("has tag equals to: " + tag);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(final View view) {
            Object viewTag = view.getTag();
            if (viewTag == null) {
                return tag == null;
            }

            return viewTag.equals(tag);
        }
    };
}
```